# Extracting the common code of handling response from callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the below code, I can extract the response handling code and place it in a different callback function and then pass the name of the callback function. However, I won't be able to do it because from within the code I have to return a response with a message and status code, and hence the code is tightly coupled with the **res** variable. I am not able to refactor this code such that I can take out the response handling code to a separate function and then can use it for other post calls. Is there any coding pattern to achieve it?

```
function saveCompany(req, res) {
    let headers = req.headers;
    let url = req.url;
    request.post(
        {
            uri: url,
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json",
                Authorization: headers.authorization
            },
            json: true,
            body: req.body
        },
        (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(response.statusCode).send(error)
            }

            // I don't know if the 3xx responses come here, if so you'll want to handle them appropriately
            if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode >= 300) {
                return res.status(response.statusCode).send({
                    message: 'Error while getting result.'
                 });
            }

            let bodyData = response ? response.body : response;
            return res.send(bodyData);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass `res` as an argument to the callback function, in addition to `error`, `response`, and `body` which are passed already. then you would be able to do something like this:

```js
function saveCompany(req, res) {
    let headers = req.headers;
    let url = req.url;
    request.post(
        {
            uri: url,
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json",
                Authorization: headers.authorization
            },
            json: true,
            body: req.body
        },
        (error, response, body) => cb(error, response, body, res))
}

const cb = (error, response, body, res) => {
  if (error) {
                return res.status(response.statusCode).send(error)
            }

            // I don't know if the 3xx responses come here, if so you'll want to handle them appropriately
            if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode >= 300) {
                return res.status(response.statusCode).send({
                    message: 'Error while getting result.'
                 });
            }

            let bodyData = response ? response.body : response;
            return res.send(bodyData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this bro. I didn't know I could do this. This was a great help to improve my javascript knowledge and saved a lot of lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern I use for my external API request handler is given below.

```
/**
 * Request handler function.
 *
 * @param {*} uri
 * @param {*} body
 * @param {*} headers
 * @param {*} onSuccess
 * @param {*} onError
 */
function reqHandler(uri, body, headers, onSuccess, onError) {
    request.post(
        {
            uri,
            headers,
            body,
            json: true,
        },
        (error, response) => {
            if (error) {
                return typeof onError === 'function' && onError(error, response);
            }
            // Call the error handler with message.
            if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode >= 300) {
                return (
                    typeof onError === 'function' &&
                    onError(error, response, 'Error while getting message.')
                );
            }
            // Call the success handler with the response.
            return typeof onSuccess === 'function' && onSuccess(response);
        },
    );
}

/**
 * Your controller function.
 *
 * @param {*} req
 * @param {*} res
 */
function saveCompany(req, res) {
    const onSuccess = (response) => {
        let bodyData = response ? response.body : response;
        return res.send(bodyData);
    };

    const onError = (error, response, message) => {
        return res.status(response.statusCode).send(message || error);
    };

    // Initiate the request.
    reqHandler(req.url, req.body, req.headers, onSuccess, onError);
}
```

With this design, `reqHandler` does not care about `req` and `res`. It just takes the parameters it needs for making an external API request. If callback functions are given, the `reqHandler` executes them when appropriate.

Your controller code should execute the `reqHandler` function passing the necessary parameters including the success/error handler functions.

One issue with this design is the need to create an `onSuccess` and `onError` callback function on every controller that needs to make a request. If the success/error handler is going to have the same definition for all the requests, then you should extend the `res` class/object to include these functions and pass them to the `reqHandler`